# How to convert entity object to model class object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework. I want to know whether there is a way to convert entity type to the model class

```
public UserModel GetUserDetailsById(int userId)
{
    using (var db = new klpm04222014Entities())
    {
         return db.klpm_user.Single(x => x.UserID == userId);
    }
}
```

but it is giving error stating that

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'klpm_user' to 'UserModel'
```

Comment: Did you try adding an explicit cast?

Comment: How is typeof `klpm_user` related to typeof `UserModel`? Do they contain similar properties?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes they have same properties

Comment: Then you could use a `.Select` - e.g. `return db.klpm_user.Single(x => x.UserID == userId).Select(x => new UserModel { ID = x.ID, Name = x.Name, etc.... });`

Comment: @JunaidKirkire i tried like this db.klpm_user.Single(x => x.UserID == userId) as UserModel but it is giving can't convert via reference converstion

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is not giving select method. it is only returning model/entity properties

Comment: @user1655222 Is `db.klpm_user` a child-class of  `UserModel`? Also, `Select()` is a LINQ-method so you need to include the appropriate namespaces.

Comment: Oops, The `.Select()` needs to be before the `Single()`

Comment: Your `klpm_user` should be of type `DbSet<UserModel>` (more precisely) in the first place.

Comment: If you have lots of classes you with to do this with then I would suggest looking at [Automapper](http://automapper.org/).

Answer (score 1):

```
public UserModel GetUserDetailsById(int userId)
{
    using (var db = new klpm04222014Entities())
    {                                
        var user = db.klpm_user.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserID == userId);
        if(user != null) 
        {
            // map the properties of your entity to the UserModel
            return new UserModel {
                UserID = user.UserID,
                ...
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your klpm_user with a sort of a generator

```
partial class klpm_user
{
    public UserModel GUserModel
    {
        get 
        { 
            return new UserModel{
               UserID = user.UserID,
               ....};
        }
    }
}
```

Then use

```
db.klpm_user.Single(x => x.UserID == userId).GUserModel;
```

This keeps the generation at a central place. If you modify your datastructure, you will only need to change the code there not everywhere.

Comment: This is not good practice, I would really try to keep this kind of code outside the entity classes. The same could be achieved with an extension method.